# Keeping only first 10 records in a specific subarray

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have some JSON which has the following format:

```
{
  "mainKey": [
    {
      "ID": "1018",
      "dish": "Fish",
      "desert": "Ice cream",
      "drink": "Cola"
    },
    {
      "ID": "1019",
      "dish": "Pizza",
      "desert": "Cake",
      "drink": "Water"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "anotherKey": [
    {
      "something": "something",
      "something": 123,
      "something": 123
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

There are lots of keys and lots of data, I have shortened it to show the basic structure.  This JSON is in a variable called `$response`.  I am first converting this into an array:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

There are a couple of keys I needed to `unset`, so I simply loop the array an unset them:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    if($key === 'mainKey') {

    }
    unset($response['another_key']);
    unset($response['yet_another_key']);
}
```

I am not unsetting all keys, just a couple.  What I am trying to do now is work on the `mainKey`, which is why I have included an if statement in the loop.

How can I keep just the first 10 records from `mainKey`?  I have seen things like `splice`, but will this preserve the other keys in my array? Will this also preserve my indexes as these are important to me?

What would be the most efficient way to do this considering that `mainKey` has over 100k records?

Comment: Create a counter, `$i = 1;` outside the foreach, then an expression inside the foreach, `if($i++ >= 10)`

Comment: foreach(array_slice($response['mainkey'],0,10) as $val) { // do staff} unset($response;'mainkey'); foreach($response as $val ) { // do other }

Comment: If you only want to work with `mainkey`, you can simply `$data = $response['mainKey'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loop is necessary; functions can do this job in a very clean and concise way.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Rd1Gu))

```
$black_keys = array_flip(['another_key', 'yet_another_key']);    // blacklist

$array = array_diff_key(json_decode($json, true), $black_keys);  // decode and filter
$array['mainKey'] = array_slice($array['mainKey'], 0, 10);       // truncate mainKey subarray

var_export($array);
```

Alternatively, this will be slightly better performing:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
unset($array['another_key'], $array['yet_another_key']);
$array['mainKey'] = array_slice($array['mainKey'], 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `mainKey` will have numerically based keys, you can create a filter that will remove all items that fall outside of a given range.

```
<?php

$json = '{
  "mainKey": [
    {
      "ID": "1018",
      "dish": "Fish",
      "desert": "Ice cream",
      "drink": "Cola"
    },
    {
      "ID": "1019",
      "dish": "Pizza",
      "desert": "Cake",
      "drink": "Water"
    }
  ],
  "anotherKey": [
    {
      "ID": "something",
      "dish": "123",
      "desert": "123"
    }
  ]
}';

$response = json_decode($json, true);

// If needed, unset your keys 
unset($response['anotherKey']);    
...

// Now, let's work only with `mainKey`
$mainKey = $response['mainKey'];

// Create a range of keys to keep
$allowed  = range(0, 10);

// Finally, filter out all keys not in the range you specified.
$filtered = array_filter(
    $mainKey,
    function ($key) use ($allowed) {
        return in_array($key, $allowed);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

// `$filtered` now only has keys 0-10. 
var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: I think this is very close.  It obtains the first 10 elements from mainkey.  One thing it does not do though is keep my other keys.  So say I wanted to keep anotherKey and not unset it, can I have this alongside the filtered array?

Comment: For sure - don't `unset($response['anotherKey']);` and then you can retrieve it when you need it: `$anotherKeyData = $reponse['anotherKey'];`

Comment: The `$filtered` process is way over-complicated.  Using `array_filter()` and `range()` and `in_array()` is the looooong way around.  I do not recommend this answer.  See my demo.

Comment: Fair enough. Nice solution.